# Angular Ag-grid how to Expand a row on click

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

Angular Ag Grid
when clicked on particular row how can i expand that row Height here i edited code in Stackbiz
[click here for Edit Data](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-zps23h?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

This is running Example from ag grid Tutorial [Grid Tutorial Explame](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/master-detail/)

Answer (score -1):

Angular Data Grid: Master / Detail available only for Enterprise use

[available only for Enterprise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mvl8C.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).